# LINQ / async / await

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

Trying to understand why the tasks start when ToArray() is executed.
and why the breakpoint I put in the DoSomething method is never hit.

```
private async void MyMethod()
{
        await NewMethod();
        string[] array = { "http://google.com", "http://microsoft.com"};
        IEnumerable<Task<string>> query = from url in array select DoSomething(url);
        Task<string>[] tasks = query.ToArray();
        string[] contents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task<string> DoSomething(string url)
{
        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        string content = await hc.GetStringAsync(url);
        return content;
 }
```

if the ToArray() actually starts the tasks, the execution should stop at the breakpoints in the DoSomething method, correct?

thank you

Comment: that is the behavior of linq. Actual query doesn't execute unless you want to something with the result set. Look at deferred and immediate query execution in linq.

Comment: Provide the `DoSomething` code and show where do you put the breakpoint there. There are some Task's there being returned that you still need to execute I believe.

Comment: And show us how do you run the `Task`s (`await`, `WaitAll()`, `WhenAny()` and so on).

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: `async void` should only be used with event handlers. If you don't want your method to return anything, use `async Task`. Otherwise you'll encounter unexpected problems, as you *can't* wait for an `async void` method to complete. Your application may terminate before `MyMethod`. The breakpoints may never be hit because the test/application ended

Comment: I marked the method as async Task and it worked, execution stopped at the breakpoint, thank you.

Comment: I have provided the code implementation of what @PanagiotisKanavos has suggested, in case Task, await is obliged to wait before continuation is fired but that's not the case with the Void, thus calling method is exiting even when your asynchronous processing using HttpClient is going on as expected, even when no caller remains to receive the result this is like Fire and Forget. Shall always use Task not Void